# Pandoc loses Section numbers as well as Figure /table references. Doesn't show superscripts

Tags: sectioning, labels, pandoc

I have a supervisor who is uncomfortable with LaTeX and wants a Word document.
It is a sizeable document with many cross referencing between sections and chapters. I used pandoc to make the conversion.

My code is: `pandoc Compiled.tex -o output.odt --bibliography MyLibrary.bib`

I have the following problems:

1. The section numbers are lost.
2. Many tables are empty because the numbers were written using siunitx package. For example \num{2.12(12)e-16}. In fact, it doesn't play well with siunitx at all when numbers and units are written with it.
3. The superscripts and plus/minus signs are off. It inconsistently tanslates things in math mode between $ $ either as an image or writes text with the $ signs at both ends.
4. Figure/table references isn't shown properly. Instead of saying Table 1.2.1, it says Table [Tab:Cell culture].
5. Things written in \textit{} are all lost.

I know this list seems long, but I feel there must be a couple of simple tricks or commands I'm missing to get this right.

I use pdflatex, Linux Mint 20 and biber 2.14 (beta). My frontend is TexMaker although I don't think it really matters here (does it?)

Comment: Open `Compiled.pdf ` with ms word (using 2013) instead of using  pandoc.

Comment: Don't have a Windows system. Tried telling this to my supervisor, but not very happy about this.

Comment: If the use case is that your supervisor wants to add comments, highlighting etc. to the text then maybe sending compiled.pdf and asking your supervisor to use a pdf viewer that supports making annotations would be an option.

Comment: Try the free service https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/pdf-to-word.html

Comment: Aside that some specific problems could have some solution (use \emph instead \textit, for instance) export LaTeX to something will always produce problems as soon as you go over most basic commands. If you can survive with basic LaTeX (without `sinutix`, for instance), write in markdown and export to LaTeX, HTML or ODT as needed.

Comment: This isn't a complete fix for your problems, but pandoc does have an option, `--number-sections`, that will number sections and subsections in Word, and references will be correct. I haven't found a way to number figures and tables, though.